# Using jQuery Update Audio Player when a new track is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I made a page in asp.net which has unordered list of 40 audio songs and a well designed audio player. I need a jQuery function that when I click any of the list item then the audio player should update itself and change the track.

```
 <ul class="rounded-list">
    <li class="audioList">List item</li>
    <li class="audioList">List item</li>
    <li class="audioList">List item</li>
    <li class="audioList">List item</li>
    <li class="audioList">List item</li>
    <li class="audioList">List item</li>
</ul>



<div id="audio-player-div" class="audio-width">
    <audio preload="auto" class="audio-player">
                <source src="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix.mp3" />
                <source src="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix.wab" />
                <source src="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix.ogg" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

I have this list of tracks and need to update the audio track, when I click any of the list item it should add it with the extension of track along with itself.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on updated question

HTML:

```
<ul class="rounded-list">
    <li class="audioList" data-track="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix1">1</li>
    <li class="audioList" data-track="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix2">2</li>
    <li class="audioList" data-track="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix3">3</li>
    <li class="audioList" data-track="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix4">4</li>
    <li class="audioList" data-track="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix5">5</li>
    <li class="audioList" data-track="Audio/BlueDucks_FourFlossFiveSix6">6</li>
</ul>



<div id="audio-player-div" class="audio-width">
    <audio preload="auto" class="audio-player"></audio>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var trackName = $(this).data('track');
    $('.audio-player').empty();
    $('.audio-player').append('<source src="'+ trackName +'.mp3" />');
    $('.audio-player').append('<source src="'+ trackName +'.wab" />');
    $('.audio-player').append('<source src="'+ trackName +'.ogg" />');
});
```

Comment: This should work. Explain what part isn't working and what, if any, errors you are getting.

Comment: You need to amend this code to your environment; copy/pasting this won't work.

Comment: Can you please explain it as I am new to jQuery and didn't understand these functions...!!!

Comment: I am using this audio player which I have downloaded about one month earlier.... [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/)

Comment: Please link the audio player you are using and tell me what errors you are getting? Be specific, I can't mind-read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help dear...!!! I found the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952870/cant-dynamically-load-html5-audio-with-firefox) and transformed it...!!! I used the audio player from [tumpanus](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/). Thanks again for your help...!!!

Comment: Now I have the same problem with the video file which is not playing as I click on another list item... and have no idea what to do...!!!